# Looking for a soft substance that doesn't dissolve underwater

Tags: communication, materials, underwater

I'm writing a story that takes place entirely underwater, mostly in a deep sea town and shallower city. Both are underwater and populated by beings who can survive underwater.

My thinking is that they send messages to each other by taking a soft clay-like material (let's call it substance x until someone thinks of what it should be) and writing on it, then giving it to a messenger. The messenger takes this wad of substance x with the writing on it and delivers it to the recipient.

When they are done the wad is given back, the letters are smushed away, and it is reused. What material should this be?

It needs to be something that can be made of substances found in the ocean, can be made underwater, doesn't dissolve into the saltwater, lasts a fairly long time, and is inexpensive.

Is there a real-world substance that meets all these requirements, or am I gonna have to make something up?

Comment: I read the title of your question and immediately thought "BluTac!" Alas, it is not a valid answer to your question :(

Comment: Oh wait! This is a duplicate of https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59791/what-could-an-aquatic-civilization-use-to-write-on-with. I didn't even notice before I wrote my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could an aquatic civilization use to write on/with?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59791/what-could-an-aquatic-civilization-use-to-write-on-with)

Comment: Its only a duplicate if you ignore the "soft substance which retains writing but can be smoothed flat" requirement. The linked duplicate doesn't mention spermaceti. for @Cloudy7 example.

Answer (score 52):

What you described is an old invention:the **[wax tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax_tablet)**.

**[Spermaceti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermaceti)** from sperm whales is just one of many waxes your underwater people could use. Some of the fishes also contain significant quantities of wax. If you need only a short-term solution, animal fat would also do the job.

I couldn't find any seaweed that secretes waxes, so I hope your underwater people are not vegan.

Comment: Agh, I was just about to hit "post" on that very idea

Comment: @StarfishPrime have a +1 from me :)

Comment: +1 for correct use of _[fishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish#Fish_or_fishes)_.

Comment: @user1717828: A perennial argument I still don’t know the answer to is whether or not it’s appropriate to talk about ‘sheeps ’ when discussing breeds of sheep.

Comment: @JoeBloggs, Yes, you can use _sheeps_ in both academic and colloquial settings.  If anyone questions it, you have my permission to rely fully on the authority of internet citizen `user1717828`.

Comment: A wax tablet is called a tabula, and the writing tool is a stylus.  There's a good chapter about the tabula in Writing on the Wall.

Answer (score 26):

**Braids of seaweed.**

The ancient Inca used knotted fibers, or *quipu*, to record events and information. With enough effort, seaweed could be manipulated (slicing then braiding) into thin cords, which could then function in a similar way as quipu. I wouldn't be sure about the lifespan of these cords -- it depends on the manufacturing process -- but these makeshift quipu could have knots tied or untied, and would be relatively light or even buoyant in water.

Comment: Not dumb.  I was think of knotted seaweed myself but didn't know how to make it work.  I didn't know about quipu and appreciate the chance to learn about it.  Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: Quipus could not only record numbers on a string.  They could also convey what IT people would call a tree structure, by attaching substrings to strings.  The quipucamayoq, expert in this, could convey very detailed and subtle info.  If you have this, you almost don't need an alphabet.

Answer (score 18):

You don't have to go back in time very far to reach a point where marine-derived hydrocarbons pretty much made the world go round. The catch being that you have to kill rather intelligent, large and dangerous predators who share your environment.

Enter the sperm whale, whose head is filled with [an extremely useful collection of waxes and oils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermaceti) which may be extracted and refined to produce exactly the sort of material you'd be interested in. By way of a bonus, it also produces another kind of oily wax, [ambergris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambergris). This is much rarer, so you would only use it for special occasions, but it would still suffice.

In both cases, you want to keep your message tablets safe in a heavy container or framework, as the waxes would be lighter than water and quickly lost if dropped.

Waxy molecules *are* found in various marine plants and animals in smaller quantities, so you don't have to wave your hands too hard to invent something slightly more easily and ethically sourceable. The main waxy component of spermaceti, [cetyl palmitate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetyl_palmitate) is found in some corals. I'm sure you could conjure up a wax coral or sponge that produced it in usefully harvest-able quantities

Answer (score 7):

If you want a pliable material that can be collected undersea without having to kill anything, you might want to consider a bituminous clay or asphalt-like material formed in the vicinity of an undersea [asphalt volcano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asphalt_volcano).

High viscosity hydrocarbon fluids mixed with fine silt or sand produce an oil-based clay-like substance that can be scraped or carved to form letters. The marks will last a long time as long as the temperature remains below a certain point, but can easily be erased by simply heating the surface via friction. Rapidly rubbing the surface softens and smooths the markings.

Comment: Clay is not water-soluble, especially if it's oil based, +1

Comment: I can see "heating via friction" being awkward for what would appear to be a minimally technological underwater society...

Comment: I specifically mentioned heating via friction because it does **not** require any advanced technology and **can** be done underwater, unlike other options such as fire or solar heating.

Comment: @barbecue: The water is going to carry away the thermal energy resulting from friction very quickly without much increase in temperature of the "tablet"

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think you fully appreciate the physics involved. The friction occurs at the point of contact between two surfaces. There is very little water in between the two surfaces, and the small amount that may be there is easily heated. The fact that the heat may be rapidly dissipated by the water once you separate the surfaces is irrelevant, because the softening and reshaping of the surface has already occurred at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not 100% what you’re looking for, but you could use the bones of aquatic animals to carve into (I’m thinking a runic alphabet like Ogham, which was designed to be notched into materials like wood). Then, when you’re done with the message, you can file the surface smooth and start again. Obviously this will wear out the bones over time, but it might work as a temporary solution (and fairly easy to implement, as bones are probably going to be relatively abundant in a decently-populated underwater civilisation).

Answer (score 2):

I like that we are trying to find a realistic substance to suit some wonderfully unrealistic characters! I think the sperm whale may be the winner but my immediate thought was putty; the smooshy stuff they used use to put window panes in place. It's sort of fawn colored and can be scribbled on. Its waterproof for sure, to keep the rain out but fully underwater, I don't know...Good luck, I love the idea of your underwater community :) 
(If you are stuck, maybe they can blow bubbles in the manner of old smoke signals?! )

Comment: Hmm... how would we derive putty from underwater substances? The question asks for substances found underwater =)

Answer (score 1):

Why does the substance have to be soft? Scraping on a rock (slate) with another rock (chalk) would work as well underwater as it does above.

Comment: Chalk washes off a little too easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question very generic, so you can use it not only for writing tablets, but ANYTHING in your underwater world.

What you are looking for are **hydrophobic substances** such as oil, fat or wax.

For your writing you'll want fat-derived substances, given that wax will be too hard in the cold.
But simply take a light granite tablet and slather some thickened, darkened grease on it.
By "writing" on it you get light letters on a dark surface, and with your fingers or a simple ruler you can "delete" writing as well instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If your race as access to metals, and if they are stronger than humans, gold would be the perfect match. 
Especially if they're somewhat advanced, as there's a lot of gold floating in the oceans.
The gold could be filtered out they would have a more or less infinite source.

Comment: I suspect if they were technologically advanced enough to extract macroscopic amounts of gold from seawater, they wouldn't be looking for a wax tablet substitute.

Comment: They are not that technologically advanced.

Answer (score -1):

**Fish**
Carve the message into a fish, the recipient eats the fish and sends back another fish with reply carved into it.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that dead fish will fail the "_lasts a fairly long time_" requirement. Also, writing legibly on a fish by carving is not straightfoward (I invite you to try; please supply pictures) especially if you want to write fairly densely.

Comment: @StarfishPrime What about a big fish? Like a whale

Comment: @Halhex no matter how big the whale is, it still isn't a fish.